# How to join a list of 8 32 hexadecimal data into single 256 bit number list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am splitting and sending my data as below

256 bit data :
1780731860627700044960722568376592200742329637303199754547598369979440671

splitted into 8 32bit hex :
[0x1c1d1e1fL, 0x18191a1bL, 0x14151617L, 0x10111213L, 0xc0d0e0fL, 0x8090a0bL, 0x4050607L, 0x10203L]

now I got the data vice versa ,

[0x1c1d1e1f, 0x18191a1b, 0x14151617, 0x10111213, 0xc0d0e0f, 0x8090a0b, 0x4050607, 0x10203]

now I want to stitch it back to 256 bit number . I tried to achieve it by using ".join" , but it didn't give me the results I wanted .

my current code :

```
    str_data = [str(i) for i in data]
    print '[{}]'.format(', '.join(x for x in str_data))
    int_data = int("".join(str_data))
    print int_data
    data = [int_data]
```

for above code , I am getting 
[471670303, 404298267, 336926231, 269554195, 202182159, 134810123, 67438087, 66051]
4716703034042982673369262312695541952021821591348101236743808766051

which is not I want .

Comment: Can you provide more code as to how you are splitting it, so maybe we can help you better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each number (from the lst in reverse order) gets shifted by 32 bits and added together. So we can just multiply each number by (2**32)**i, where `i` is the position of the number in the list and then sum all the numbers

```
>>> lst = [0x1c1d1e1f, 0x18191a1b, 0x14151617, 0x10111213, 0xc0d0e0f, 0x8090a0b, 0x4050607, 0x10203]
>>> sum(n* (2**32)**i for i, n in enumerate(lst))
1780731860627700044960722568376592200742329637303199754547598369979440671
```

Comment: Hello Sunitha , thank you so much , it worked , can you please edit with bit of an explanation :)  .

Comment: absolutely brilliant . thanks for the help and good information :)

Comment: @chepner. Isn't `1780731860627700044960722568376592200742329637303199754547598369979440671` the expected number, as OP has started with that number

Comment: Ah, I see, it's an endianness issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` (`functools.reduce` in Python 3) and bitwise operators.

```
>>> lst = [0x1c1d1e1fL, 0x18191a1bL, 0x14151617L, 0x10111213L, 0xc0d0e0fL, 0x8090a0bL, 0x4050607L, 0x10203L]
>>> reduce(lambda acc, x: acc<<32 | x, reversed(lst))
1780731860627700044960722568376592200742329637303199754547598369979440671L
>>> hex(_)
'0x102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1fL'
```

This is also about 4 times faster than repeated exponentiation.

Comment: still we are using 2.7.15 , we have plans to move to python soon . Thank you for answering

Comment: Just to be clear, `reduce` is available as a built-in function in Python 2; it was moved to the `functools` module in the standard library in Python 3.